# Discriminant of number field

Tags: number-theory

Calculate the discriminant of the number field $K =  \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is root of the polynomial $x^3 - x- 1$.

any help is welcome, cheers!

Comment: @lhf find the roots?

Comment: There are formulas for the discriminant of a cubic...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $f(X) = X^3 + aX + b$ be a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.
The discriminant $d$ of $f(X)$ is $-(4a^3 + 27b^2)$.
In your case $d = -23$.
Since $-23$ is square free ($23$ is a prime), $1, \alpha, \alpha^2$ is an integral basis of $K$.
Hence the discriminant of $K$ is $-23$.