# Computing Discriminant of Elements in Number Fields in General

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose that $\beta$ is the root of an arbitrary irreducible cubic polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, and $\beta \notin Q$. Let $K=Q(\beta)$. I'm curious how to compute the discriminant of $(1,\beta,\beta^2)$ in general, when we might not know the exact value of $\beta$.

Perhaps that is too broad, so let's consider an example: $f(x) = x^3 - x - 1$, in relation to the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201926/discriminant-of-number-field), and $\beta$ is a root of this. The answer there suggests to use a known formula for the discriminant of a cubic, but how can I do this from first principles: namely, knowing just the definition of the discriminant as $det(Tr_{K/Q}(a_ia_j)) =: d(a_1...a_n)$? I'm unable to find anything about this online.

Comment: The determinant formula has a convenient form for polynomials $x^3+ax+b\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ as $-4a^3-27b^2$. The formula is proved using the definition of determinant in terms of roots of polynomial and then applying Vieta formulas. You should check *Introductory Algebraic Number Theory* by Alaca and Williams where they show all the steps involved in deriving this formula. They also derive the determinant formula for $x^4+ax+b$.

Comment: Further your title of the question is about determinant of number fields which is much harder than finding determinant of the minimal polynomial of the primitive element of the field. It would be nice to update the title to match the contents of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Discriminant $d(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ can also be defined as $(\det (\sigma_i(a_j))^2, 0\leq i, j \leq n$.

For ease of typing I will call $\beta$ as $a$ and let its conjugates be $b$ and $c$. So the discriminant is square of the determinant of following matrix

\begin{array}
&1 & 1 & 1\\
a & b & c\\
a^2 & b^2 & c^2\\
\end{array}

The determinant is $(c-b)(b-a)$ or $(a-b)(b-c)$ which is same as the discriminant of polynomial. In case you don't know the matrix we obtained is a particular type of matrix called Vandermonde matrix whose determinant has this simple formula. This can be applied for polynomial of any degree. Some of these details can be found in Number Fields by Daniel Marcus.

Comment: We still need to know the explicit values of the roots to get the determinant’s value with this, no?

Comment: No. The formula you get for discriminant is exactly how discriminant of a polynomial is defined. That other complicated formula you will see for discriminant of a cubic is not the definition. It's a way of calculating the discriminant in terms of coefficients, without knowing the roots. So if degree $n$ polynomial has roots $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ then its discriminant is $\Big(\prod_{i<j} (x_i - x_j) \Big)^2$. For example, for a quadratic $x^2 + bx + c$ with roots $x_1, x_2$ discriminant is $(x_1 - x_2)^2 = (x_1+ x_2)^2 - 4x_1x_2 = b^2 - 4c$. 
 You don't know roots but can calculate discriminant.

Comment: Right, but I'm interested in computing the explicit value of the determinant in terms of the given polynomial's coefficients, rather than the general formula you have stated in your answer. What you demonstrate in your comment for the quadratic case, for ex. - that is what I'm asking about. Thank you!

Comment: I demonstrated it in quadratic case because it was easy but as you go higher degrees the formula will become more and more complicated. I don't even know how to derive it for a cubic by algebraic manipulations but I do know how to do it using algebraic number theory. But that would be too much to write here. That's why I suggested Marcus. That's where I learnt it from.